# Send one-shot ViewModel event when using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Previously I was able to fire a navigation event from ViewModel to a fragment using [Event](https://github.com/mtali/gopods/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/colisa/podplay/util/Event.kt) class

Something like this

[ViewModel]

```
private val _navigate = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
val navigate: LiveData<Event<String>> =_navigate

fun onClickNext(id: String) {
     // some processing 
     _navigate.value = Event(id)
}
```

[Fragment]

```
viewModel.navigation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
    navigateToUser(it)
})
```

How can I do the same thing with Jetpack Compose?

> Scenario: User clicks login button, the event goes to ViewModel, the
> ViewModel does some processing and if the operation is successful fire
> an event to Compose view to initiate navigation

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this

```
fun LoginRoute(viewModel: ....., onLoginSuccess:() -> Unit) {
   LoginScreen(
     onClickLogin = {viewModel.onLogin(onLoginSuccess)}
   )
}

fun LoginScreen(onClickLogin: () -> Unit) {
    // Invoke login somethow
}

class LoginViewModel (): ViewModel() {
    fun onLogin(success: () -> Unit) {
        // Show loading or something
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Call repo/use-case to authenticate the user 
            if failed
                // Show error
            else 
                success()
                // Remove loading
        }
        
    }
}
```

If you use [state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting) your ViewModel is supposed to have the supposed entered username / password / credential.

Simple . . .

Check out [this](https://github.com/mtali/quick/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/colisa/quick/features/spash/SpashScreen.kt) example if you want to learn more